# connect to mongodb from .then

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Hi i have want to connect to mongo db to check if user is already registered or not if not i want to save user phone_number and make a code for his login and if he is already registered i want to just send the code for login 
the problem is when i wrote the code it doesn't check the (if) statement and continues to end and send empty error

```
userModel.findOne({phone_number: req.body.phone_number}).then(function (err, res) {
        console.log('if start');
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            if (res.length){
                codeModel.create({
                    phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
                    code_Number: Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1000)
                }).then(function (created) {
                    console.log('response then');
                    res.status(200).send(created);
                })
            }
            else {
                    console.log("blah blah blah");
                    userModel.create(req.body).then(function (jobs) {
                        res.status(200).send(jobs)
                    })
                }
        }
```

Comment: [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) does not have `(err,res)` it's only `res`. The `err` is handled in [`.catch()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch). Also by your "model" naming and the `.create()` method, this would be "mongoose".

Comment: yes it's mongoose so if i fix what u said my code should be fine ?

Comment: You should be reading those links. Promises are different to callbacks. You also have continuation problems in the logic. But one step at a time.

Comment: E11000 duplicate key error collection: jobFinder.users index: phone_number_1 dup key >>>>> i got this error after removing it >> can u help me provide best solution for this code and please make it as an answer so i can close the question section and make you'r answer (the solution)

Answer (score 0):

i found it myself the error is do to .then placement it should be after function

```
userModel.findOne({phone_number:req.body.phone_number},function (err, user) {
        if (err){
            res.status(400).send(err)
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result + " data ");
            console.log('user');
            if (result == null || result == ''){
                //user peida nashod
                console.log('peida nashod');

                userModel.create(req.body).then(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp + " resp ");
                }).catch(next);

                codeModel.create(req.body).then(function (code) {
                    console.log(code);
                    res.status(200).send({
                        message:"afarin",
                        code: code
                    })
                }).catch(next)
            }
            else {
                codeModel.create(req.body).then(function (code) {
                    console.log(code);
                    res.status(200).send({
                        message:"afarin",
                        code: code
                    })
                }).catch(next)
            }

    }).catch(next)
```